# SSRS 2019 - Applying user permissions to reports in bulk

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

First time posting on here.

I've deployed over 400 reports to SSRS and I'm trying to find a way to apply user permissions to the reports in bulk, but I'm having zero luck.

I don't want the reports to inherit the same permissions from the parent folder.

Thanks in advance for your help

Applying the user permission to each report one by one and it takes a very long time. Would like to find a quicker method

Comment: If you don't want them the to follow the parent permissions, how do you envisage setting permissions in bulk? All the permissions are set in reportserver.dbo.policyuserrole and related to dbo.users, dbo.roles and dbo.catalog but I'm not sure if it's safe to add new records to PolicyUserRole (it might be OK - I've never tried)